# Unable to install Mongo-DB on Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Core 18.04

Tags: pi-3b+, ubuntu, arm, mongodb

I am trying to install mongoDB on my **Raspberry Pi 3b+, which has an ARM 4-Core 64 bit processor.**

I was trying to install MongoDB on my Pi just as mentioned in their [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) but unfortunately I get the error messages:

> N: Skipping acquire of configured file
>   'multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository
>   'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease'
>   doesn't support architecture 'arm64'

and:

> E: Unable to locate package
>   mongodb-org

The first message really surprises me as MongoDB mentions that it should be compatible with ARM64 processors: [Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/)

I also made sure that I have 64 bit by issuing the command `uname -m` which returns aarch64 as a result.

More information about my system:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I have spent quite a lot of time on that topic now and would be very thankful for an answer that solves it.

Comment: `bionic/mongodb-org/4.0` has no arm64 image, but `bionic/mongodb-org/4.1` does

Answer (score 0):

Have you try below command

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

If not, go with this and try.
Alternative solution for your problem are

- Use docker image of mongodb
- [mongodb cloud](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas)

Comment: Using the cloud is not an option. sudo apt-get install mongodb does not install the newest official mongoldb server. A docker image also does not work.

Comment: I think no link available for downloading new version of mongodb on offical site of mongodb for arm arch. And I think docker image option is better than.